# Encode and decode javascript file or blob to base64

Tags: javascript, python, file

I am creating a web app with react as frontend and python ariadne (graphql) as backend. I want to allow the user to upload a file.

Essentially, I first want to convert the file to base64 in react, pass it to graphql mutation, and then decode the base64 string back to file in javascript.

Just like `base64.b64encode` & `base64.b64decode` in python.

Is there a way to this with a javascript file or blob object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a file but note that it's an async call:

```js
const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const r = new FileReader();
    r.readAsDataURL(file);
    r.onerror = error => reject(error);
    r.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
});


// use with await toBase64(YOUR_FILE);
```

To reconvert the base64 to a file use this:

```js
fetch(YOUR_DATA)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const file = new File([blob], "YOUR_FILE_NAME" ,{ type: YOUR_MIME_TYPE })
  })
```